# cannot resolve symbol 'Lowpassfilter'

Tags: android, compass

I have been using Compass Code from website http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-how-to-make-a-compass-application-for-android/ .
Actually i am newly developing a compass application i have been getting an error Cannot Resolve symbol 'LowPassFilter'. I have imported every possible files still the same error

```
@Override
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  boolean accelOrMagnetic = false;

// get accelerometer data
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
  // we need to use a low pass filter to make data smoothed
  smoothed = **LowPassFilter**.filter(event.values, gravity);
  gravity[0] = smoothed[0];
  gravity[1] = smoothed[1];
  gravity[2] = smoothed[2];
  accelOrMagnetic = true;

} else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
  smoothed = **LowPassFilter**.filter(event.values, geomagnetic);
  geomagnetic[0] = smoothed[0];
  geomagnetic[1] = smoothed[1];
  geomagnetic[2] = smoothed[2];
  accelOrMagnetic = true;

}

// get rotation matrix to get gravity and magnetic data
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotation, null, gravity, geomagnetic);
// get bearing to target
SensorManager.getOrientation(rotation, orientation);
 // east degrees of true North
 bearing = orientation[0];
 // convert from radians to degrees
 bearing = Math.toDegrees(bearing);

 // fix difference between true North and magnetical North
 if (geomagneticField != null) {
 bearing += geomagneticField.getDeclination();
 }

 // bearing must be in 0-360
 if (bearing < 0) {
  bearing += 360;
 }

 // update compass view
 compassView.setBearing((float) bearing);

 if (accelOrMagnetic) {
  compassView.postInvalidate();
 }

updateTextDirection(bearing); // display text direction on screen function
}
```

Comment: LowpassFilter is another class, that provides a lowpass filter (that's an engineering term for something that only lets low frequency signals through, and blocks high ones.  So it would ignore big changes in data, probably by capping them).  YOu need to include that in your app as well, right now you aren't.

Comment: i have tried to include every class possible but i am still not finding which one to import could you tell me which class i have to.

Comment: Its not a missing import, its a missing file.  But it isn't your fault-  the guy who wrote the tutorial didn't post it.

Comment: Yes Thank you @GabeSechan

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer at http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Sensor/compass/com_jwetherell_compass_commonLowPassFilter_java.htm.

```
package com.jwetherell.compass.common;
/* w  w  w  . j  a v a  2 s  .co m*/
/**
 * This class implements a low-pass filter. A low-pass filter is an electronic
 * filter that passes low-frequency signals but attenuates (reduces the
 * amplitude of) signals with frequencies higher than the cutoff frequency. The
 * actual amount of attenuation for each frequency varies from filter to filter.
 * It is sometimes called a high-cut filter, or treble cut filter when used in
 * audio applications.
 * 
 * @author Justin Wetherell (phishman3579@gmail.com)
 */
public class LowPassFilter {

    /*
     * Time smoothing constant for low-pass filter 0 ? ? ? 1 ; a smaller value
     * basically means more smoothing See:
     * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Discrete-time_realization
     */
    private static final float ALPHA = 0.2f;

    private LowPassFilter() {
    }

    /**
     * Filter the given input against the previous values and return a low-pass
     * filtered result.
     * 
     * @param input
     *            float array to smooth.
     * @param prev
     *            float array representing the previous values.
     * @return float array smoothed with a low-pass filter.
     */
    public static float[] filter(float[] input, float[] prev) {
        if (input == null || prev == null) throw new NullPointerException("input and prev float arrays must be non-NULL");
        if (input.length != prev.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException("input and prev must be the same length");

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            prev[i] = prev[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - prev[i]);
        }
        return prev;
    }
}
```